# Check string similarity percentage

Tags: hash, string, bytes, hash-algorithm

How can I efficiently check the similarity of two strings? Or better yet, if I have an array of strings, I want to check that the given string is less than e.g. 80 % similar to any of the other strings. One of such approaches is for example Levenshtein Algorithm.

If there already exists some contract which provides a solution for this, that would work as well.

Can this even be done in an efficient manner on-chain?